# Load page with Ajax and load new scripts if necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have a page1 which has a wrapper with articles.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
</div>
```

I am loading new articles from page2 with Ajax and appending them to the wrapper

```
    $.ajax({
        url : page_to_load,
        success : function (data) {

            $('article',data).appendTo('#wrapper');

        }
    });
```

But some of this new articles might need specific scripts that were not loaded in page1 but would be loaded if accessed directly page2.

So the problem is some of the content in new articles breaks as they are missing those scripts.

What is the best solution? I can think of checking the new loaded page scripts and compare them with the already loaded and download the new ones, but I have no idea of how to do this.

---

**EDIT**

I noticed if I set the dataType to 'html' I cant search for the scripts, although they are there:

```
$('script',data)//doesn't match anything
```

But if I do:

```
console.log(data);
```

I can see the whole page with `<html>` and `<script>` tags

Comment: `$(data).find('script')` return undefined too?

Comment: console.log($(data).find('script'));    displays this:    [script, prevObject: e.fn.init[79], context: undefined, selector: "script", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url : page_to_load,
    success : function (data) {
        // load the scripts
        var dom = $(data);
        dom.filter('script').each(function(){
            var scriptSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            if(!$('script[src="'+ scriptSrc +'"]').length && scriptSrc !== undefined) {
                var script = $("<script/>");
                script.attr('src', scriptSrc);
                $("head").append(script);
            }
        });
        // load the articles
        $('article',data).appendTo('#wrapper');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this as I won't have access to the specific scripts each article might need. I am building a wordpress theme and the user might have a plugin that will load scripts as I mentioned, so I dont have control over which scripts there will be.

Comment: ok I see. and from where do you know which scripts you have to load in the first place?

Comment: I don't understand your question,could you please elaborate?

Comment: How do you know which scripts you have to load for each article? are you loading a whole page with ajax? -and do you want to load all the scripts that are inside this loaded page?

Comment: 1.The scripts would be added automatically by any plugin the site has. 2.Im calling the whole page but just adding the <article>. 3.I want to load the scripts that are not already loaded. For example: I have jquery.js and modernizr.js at first and the Ajax-loaded page has these two and an extra custom.js script (I want to Detect this one is not already in my page and Load this custom.js only)

Comment: Ok, above you can find the working solution! (without the need of parseHTML)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any advantage in this method vs. parseHTML?

Comment: @Alvaro it's an implicit to parseHTML().If you want to achieve the same thing with an explicit call you will end up with parseHTML().Ref[Jquery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Comment: @Alvaro this solution makes use of browser caching. The other solution forces the scripts to reload each time a user refreshes your website...

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add if(!$('script[src="'+ scriptSrc +'"]').length && scriptSrc !== undefined) {   To check if the script is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem actually, if you append HTML to the Dom then script calls will be interpreted as if the page was loaded directly, just make sure you use the same parameters as the shorthand jquery $.POST method.

I actually do this all the time and the `<script src="">` are called and interpreted correctly

Just make sure you're accessing the scripts from the right scope as if the html was hardcoded on page1.

If this doesn't work, then check with the web inspector if the scripts are loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you could add a script in the AJAX call - I'm not sure of this because I haven't tried it:

```
Proxy.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(AddVersion("/Pages/Items/SearchList/SearchList.Grid.js" )));
```

Comment: The problem I have is I need to figure out which are the scripts first.

Answer (score 0):

This workflow should work :

1. After every page request :
2. Get all the script tags in the loaded page.
3. Loop over the scripts
4. If it's not loaded yet , load it.

Here is the code snippet :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost',
    success : function (data) {
        $('article',data).appendTo('#wrapper');
        $.each($.parseHTML(data,null,true),function(){
          if($(this)[0].tagName == "SCRIPT"){
              var src = $(this).attr('src');
                if($('script[src="'+ src +'"]').length){
                    $.getScript(src);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I thought but $('script',data) doesnt return anything. If I do console.log(data); I can see the whole page with the scripts I want,,so, Im not sure why $('script',data) doesnt return anything

Comment: I set it to 'html' which I think is the correct type, isn't it?

Comment: @Alvaro updated my code. It's working jquery>=1.8. I will add the explanation when i get time

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can see the new scripts. But $.getScript is calling new and not-new scripts, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if the parseHTML (or function applied I still need time to understand correctly) has a significant impact on the performance?

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be if(!$('script[src="'+ src +'"]').length){

Comment: @Alvaro exactly , my mistake

Comment: @Alvaro this solution forces the scripts to reload each time a user refreshes your website. My solution makes use of browser caching, the scripts get loaded only once!

Answer (score 0):

**Disable async.**

```
$.ajax({
  url : page_to_load,
  async: false, 
  success : function (data) {  
   $('article',data).appendTo('#wrapper');
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain this?

Comment: I do not know much English, but it will help, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RequireJS or HeadJs library for calling js files.

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader and HeadJS, a small library for Responsive Design, Feature Detections & Resource Loading

HeadJs is great and useful, try it.